# LINQ, Excluding Some Items

Tags: c#, .net, linq, skip

I have the following IEnumerable:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(this.FileToExtract); // IEnumerable<string>
```

Now I want to exclude the first 3 lines using linq, What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx).

```
var linesTest = lines.Skip(3);
```

To take all but last:

```
var allButLast = linesTest.Take(linesTest.Count() - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, And how to skip the last item ?

Comment: @Jahan Keep in mind this actually reads the file twice, if the file is not too big, it's probably better to materialize the enumerable (using ToList for instance) and to work on an IList instead of an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 2):

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(this.FileToExtract).Skip(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx):

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(this.FileToExtract).Skip(3);
```